# How do i get updated values from php JSON in canvasJS?

Tags: javascript, php, canvasjs

Im stuck at trying to get updated values from the JSON array and plotting it on canvasJS.

Here is my JSON array for sensor 1:

```
[{
    "Date": "2020-01-24 07:35:46",
    "sensorValue": 213
}, {
    "Date": "2020-01-24 07:35:46",
    "sensorValue": 433
}, {
    "Date": "2020-02-10 06:03:36",
    "sensorValue": 321
}, {
    "Date": "2020-02-10 06:03:36",
    "sensorValue": 43
}, {
    "Date": "2020-02-12 03:30:57",
    "sensorValue": 4321
}]
```

Below is my index2.php file

the updateChart function doesn't seem to work. Im not sure if this is the right way to do it. 
the rationale behind the code: I wish to update the graph every few seconds with updated values retrieved thru php. if there are no updated values, the array should not change. hence the reason behind the for-loop and the date comparison.

```
<?php
    include 'getsensor.php';
?>
     <!DOCTYPE HTML>
     <html>
     <head>
     <script>
     window.onload = function() {
     <?php
        getSensor();
     ?>

     var updateInterval = 2000;
     var sensor1Data = <?php echo json_encode($json_sensor1, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>;
     var sensor2Data = <?php echo json_encode($json_sensor2, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>;

    //  sensor datapoints
     var sensor1 = [], sensor2 = [], sensor3 = [], sensor4 = [], sensor5 = [];

     var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
         zoomEnabled: true,
         title: {
             text: "Soil Moisture Reading"
         },
         axisX: {
             title: "chart updates every " + updateInterval / 1000 + " secs"
         },
         axisY:{
             includeZero: false
         }, 
         toolTip: {
             shared: true
         },
         legend: {
             cursor:"pointer",
             verticalAlign: "top",
             fontSize: 22,
             fontColor: "dimGrey",
             itemclick : toggleDataSeries
         },
         data: [{ 
                 type: "line",
                 name: "Sensor 1",
                 dataPoints: sensor1
             },
             {
                 type: "line",
                 name: "Sensor 2",
                 dataPoints: sensor2
             }]
     });

    for(var i = 0; i < sensor1Data.length; i++) {
        sensor1.push({ 
            x: new Date(sensor1Data[i].Date), 
            y: Number(sensor1Data[i].sensorValue)
        })
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < sensor2Data.length; i++) {
        sensor2.push({ 
            x: new Date(sensor2Data[i].Date), 
            y: Number(sensor2Data[i].sensorValue)
        })
    }

     chart.render();
     setInterval(function(){updateChart()}, updateInterval);

     function toggleDataSeries(e) {
         if (typeof(e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
             e.dataSeries.visible = false;
         }
         else {
             e.dataSeries.visible = true;
         }
         chart.render();
     }

     function updateChart() {
         // retrieves new data from database. updates and shifts the graph.
        <?php
            getSensor();
        ?>
        var sensor1DataNew = <?php echo json_encode($json_sensor1, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>;

        var i = sensor1DataNew.length - 1;
        // retrieve the index of the new value
        for (i; i > 0; i--){
            if (sensor1DataNew[i].Date == sensor1Data[19].Date){
                break;
            }
        }

        // pushes the new values to be plotted
        for(i; i < sensor1DataNew.length; i++) {
            sensor1.push({ 
                x: new Date(sensor1DataNew[i].Date), 
                y: Number(sensor1DataNew[i].sensorValue)
            })
        }

        if(sensor1.length > 20){
            sensor1.shift();
        }

        chart.render();
     }

    }
     </script>
     </head>
     <body>
     <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>
     <script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
     </body>
     </html>
```

here is my getSensor.php file:

```
<?php
        require_once 'mysqldb.php';

        $json_sensor1 = array();
        $json_sensor2 = array();
        $json_sensor3 = array();

        function getSensor(){
            global $json_sensor1, $json_sensor2, $json_sensor3;
            global $db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name;
            /* start connection */
            $conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

            /* check connection */
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                printf("Connection failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
                exit();
            }

            # get/display datetime and sensor value        
            $sensor1 = 'SELECT Date, sensorValue  FROM sensor WHERE sensorName = "sensor 1" ORDER BY ID ASC, Date DESC LIMIT 20';
            $sensor2 = 'SELECT Date, sensorValue  FROM sensor WHERE sensorName = "sensor 2" ORDER BY ID ASC, Date DESC LIMIT 20';
            $sensor3 = 'SELECT Date, sensorValue  FROM sensor WHERE sensorName = "sensor 3" ORDER BY ID ASC, Date DESC LIMIT 20';

            // $sensor3 = 'SELECT Date, sensorName, sensorValue  FROM sensor WHERE Date IN (SELECT MAX(Date) FROM sensor WHERE sensorName = "sensor 3") ORDER BY ID ASC, Date DESC';

            $json_sensor1 = sqlQuery($conn,$sensor1);
            $json_sensor2 = sqlQuery($conn,$sensor2);
            $json_sensor3 = sqlQuery($conn,$sensor3);

            /* close connection */
            mysqli_close($conn);
        }

        function sqlQuery($conn,$sql_query){
            $json_array = array();
            if($query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql_query)){
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                    $json_array[] = $row;
                }
                /* free result set */
                mysqli_free_result($query);
            }
            return $json_array;
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, but I think the problem lies in the way you load the data (or the lack of it).

Basically you are loading the data on the PHP page render once, and that is all.
You need some ajax requests periodically to load the data instead of the PHP echo in the updateChart method. (In the initialization part it is fine)

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET", 
    url: 'getSensorData.php',
    dataType: "text", 
    async: false,
    success: function(data){
        sensor1DataNew = data;
    }
});
```

Something like this might work (with a little jquery)

Comment: isnt the data loaded when i call the updateChart function? in the updateChart function i call the php function getSensor that will update the array $json_sensor1. i declared $json_sensor1 as a global variable in php. I have added my getSensor.php code

Comment: Try to use Chrome's Developer tools to see if the data changes. You will see that even though you "call" the function via PHP, the data only updates if you reload the page.
This is a "limitation" of PHP, as it loads all your functions on page load, once, and the data stays static until the page gets reloaded again.

Unfortunately you can't mix and match javascript and PHP like this. If a page requires data load without page refresh, then unfortunately you are stuck with the good old js.